# Javascript pattern behaves weird

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

`foo` is a function that calls itself, and within it is a function `bar` which also calls itself. Then I'm exposing `bar`. But why does it later says 'foo' is `undefined`?

```
var foo = (function(){
    var bar = (function(t){
        console.log(t);
    })('test 1');

    return bar;
})();

console.log(foo); // output: undefined
```

### Update:

I would like to do something like this:

```
var foo = (function foo(){
    (function bar(t){
        console.log(t);
    })('test 1');

    return { bar : bar };
})();

foo.bar('test 2');
```

only that now `bar` is not recognized..seems like I can't self-execute once, and yet pass it as the return value..

Comment: Because `bar` is undefined, as that inner IEFE does not return anything? What did you expect it to be?

Comment: I've voted the question to be closed. thanks guys for the quick help!

Answer (score 2):

The `foo` function immediately invokes itself, so its return value is assigned to `foo`. It returns the *return value* of `bar`, since that immediately invokes itself too, and since `bar` returns `undefined`, `foo` returns `undefined` too:

```
// Outer function, immediately invoked
var foo = (function(){

    // Inner function, immediately invoked
    var bar = (function(t){
        console.log(t);
        // Implicitly return undefined
    })('test 1');

    // bar is now === undefined

    return bar;
})();

console.log(foo); // output: undefined
```

Comment: `bar` is not a function, but only a variable.

Comment: @Bergi - It's clear what I'm trying to say though. It's easier to say "bar" than "the anonymous function the return value of which is assigned to bar".

Comment: ha. how dumb of me. i need Coffey.

Comment: But if bar is a function, and we return bar… I think using correct terms is essential here to avoid any (further)confusion.

Comment: I would like to return the pointer to `bar` as a function, but have `bar` call itself

Answer (score 2):

> `foo` is a function that calls itself

No. `foo` is the *return value* of an immediate call to an anonymous function.

> But why does it later says 'foo' is `undefined`?

That function returns `bar` which is the return value of another immediate call to a different anonymous function.

The return value of that function is, since there is no `return` statement in it: `undefined` (so `bar` is `undefined` so `foo` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not behaving wierdly at all.

```
   var bar = (function(t){
        console.log(t);
        // return undefined;
    })('test 1');
   return bar; // again return undefined;
```

It has no `return` statement, therefore it is returning `undefined`. You are then returning `undefined` again, so it's obvious `foo` will also be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is not a function, but the return of the anonymous function

```
function(){
    var bar = (function(t){
        console.log(t);
    })('test 1');

    return bar;
}
```

And the return is `bar`, that is the return of the anonymous function

```
function(t){
    console.log(t);
}
```

with `t == 'test 1'`. This function returns nothing, so `bar` is undefined, as well as `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read this: You're not returning bar, you're returning the result of bar('test 1'); which is undefined.

Comment: indeed. (hammer on the head)

Comment: He does not call `bar` with anything.

Comment: Yes, I know that my comment is not literally correct, but he quickly got what I meant. The function I called "bar" is actually anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra parenthesis around your function. This turns it into a self invoking anonymous function.

This means that `foo` is set to its return value!

All you need to do is remove the extra parenthesis.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xfh58/

Comment: *You have extra parenthesis around your fuction. This turns it into a self invoking anonymous function.* — No. They turn it into a function expression. It is the pair of parenthesis that *follow* it that make it self-invoking.

Comment: My bad, im sure the correct answers will get pushed to the top.

Answer (score 0):

bar does not return a value, so foo doesn't as well.

Answer (score 0):

tBecause the bar function does not return anything. A function that does not have a return value in javascript returns undefined.

If you change bar to this:

```
var bar = (function(t){
    return t;
})('test 1');
```

you foo will no longer be undefined.

Comment: `bar` is not a function